# extracting string after matching pattern using bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

i have the following string

```
1234 1 xyz123 4321 1 456778 32124 1 abbba 56789 1 hfhfn456
```

i want to extract following substrings. The extraction is needed multiple times.

```
abbba 
456778 
hfhfn456
xyz123
```

by using bash shell,awk or sed or grep is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to print those specific fields, or were you looking to assign each one to a separate variable, or what? Have you tried solving this problem yourself? If so, what's the problem that you're having?

Comment: What is the pattern you need to match to find these strings?

Comment: It seems straightforward using `awk`. Loop through the fields in the line. If a field matches the pattern, print the next field.[

Comment: @Barmer : thanks i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You might find `awk` useful for this task. It is the idea utility for processing columnar data:

```
#!/bin/sh 

string="1234 1 xyz123 4321 1 456778 32124 1 abbba 56789 1 hfhfn456"
match1=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $9}' )
match2=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $6}' )
match3=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $12}' )
match4=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $3}' )


echo "$match1"
echo "$match2"
echo "$match3"
echo "$match4"
```

To compare their values against a per-determined set:

```
#!/bin/sh 

#abbba
#456778
#hfhfn456
#xyz123

string="1234 1 xyz123 4321 1 456778 32124 1 abbba 56789 1 hfhfn456"
match1=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $9}' )
match2=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $6}' )
match3=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $12}' )
match4=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $3}' )

if [ "$match1" = "abbba" ]
then echo "match1 is abbba"
fi
if [ "$match2" = "456778" ]
then echo "match2 is 456778"
fi
if [ "$match3" = "hfhfn456" ]
then echo "match3 is hfhfn456"
fi
if [ "$match4" = "xyz123" ]
then echo "match4 is xyz123"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If GNU coreutils are installed and the order in which the results are listed doesn't matter, you could also get away with `cut`  and `tr`:

```
echo "1234 1 xyz123 4321 1 456778 32124 1 abbba 56789 1 hfhfn456" | \
    cut -d' ' -f'3,6,9,12' | tr " " "\n"
```

Output:

```
abbba 
456778 
hfhfn456
xyz123
```